# Nested properties across property place holder configurers

Tags: java, spring

I have multiple property files, a general one called application.properties and a more specific on called [HostName].properties

The Hostname.properties is set to higher priority than application.properties.

In application.properties I set the db.url:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://${db.host}:3306/${db.schema}?autoReconnect=true&amp;sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB;
```

I also set the db.host and db.schema values in this properties file.

```
db.schema=default
db.host=localhost
```

Then in [Hostname].properties I want to override the values for db.host and db.schema:

```
db.schema=specific
db.host=specific_hostname
```

However, it seems as if this nesting is not working.

The db.schema value resolves to "specific" but the db.url property resolves to the db.schema specified in the same file as the db.url is defined in.

Consider the following test snippet:

```
@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbUrl;

@Value("${db.schema}")
private String dbSchema;

@Test
public void testUrlTest() {
    System.out.println(dbUrl);
    System.out.println(dbSchema);
}
```

First value printed out is

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB;

Second value is:

> specific

Is this by design? I would love to be able to override nesting from one property configurer to the next.

Is there some way around this?

UPDATE:
The Property place holders are configured in the spring config xml as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder order="10"
    location="classpath:xxx.yyy/application.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" ref="hostnameLookup" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean class="xxx.yyy.util.HostNameLookupFactory" id="hostnameLookup"
    autowire-candidate="false">
    <property name="prefix" value="classpath:xxx.yyy/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".properties" />
</bean>
```

The HostNameLookupFactory is a factory bean that provides the local host name.

Comment: How did you configure the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`?

Comment: So you're just using two PPC's? Maybe just swap the order of those two beans?

Comment: trailing slash is as it is. The factory bean returns classpath:xxx.yyy/[HOSTNAME].properties